# Trying to append a single row of data to a pandas DataFrame, but instead adds rows for each field of input

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add a row of data to a pandas DataFrame, but it keeps adding a separate row for each piece of data. I feel I am missing something very simple and obvious, but what it is I do not know.

```
import pandas

colNames = ["ID", "Name", "Gender", "Height", "Weight"]
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(columns = colNames)
df1.set_index("ID", inplace=True, drop=False)
i = df1.shape[0]
person = [{"ID":i},{"Name":"Jack"},{"Gender":"Male"},{"Height":177},{"Weight":75}]
df1 = df1.append(pandas.DataFrame(person, columns=colNames))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    ID  Name Gender  Height  Weight
0  0.0   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
1  NaN  Jack    NaN     NaN     NaN
2  NaN   NaN   Male     NaN     NaN
3  NaN   NaN    NaN   177.0     NaN
4  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    75.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using too many squiggly brackets. All of your data should be inside one pair of squiggly brackets. This creates a single python dictionary. Change that line to:

```
    person = [{"ID":i,"Name":"Jack","Gender":"Male","Height":177,"Weight":75}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple. Much appreciated.